# Android, preferred method for accessing 10,000+ record database on server

Tags: android, sql, database, web-services, enterprise

So I am in need of some assistance in trying to determine what I am going to need in order to accomplish a task.

Plain and simple...I am looking at accessing multiple databases some of which may contain over 10,000 records via Android.  From what I have seen web services that return JSON is the way to go for something of this nature, but I don't think that fully answers my question or know if this is the preferred way to go about this.

Digging a bit deeper...I have a few apps on the market now, but this will be my first attempt at an enterprise style app, and I have accessed public web services with a lot smaller footprint than what this is going to be.    I have little to no experience within the realm of server/network administration which is where I am getting tripped up.  This is from the ground up and I have to ability to obtain almost any resources I need to complete this task.

It appears that there is a SQL Server 2008 on the back end if that helps.  If I need to provide further details let me know.  I am looking at a solution that will handle organizational growth, scalability, authentication and ease of user...so keep that in mind too.

So what is the best practice/preferred method for doing an enterprise application with a substantial data set?  What are the big dogs doing, and how?  Both on the client side and server side.  I am trying not to "screw the pooch" out of the gates on this, and this is one of those measure twice and cut once situations which is why I am trying to garner plenty of input and assistance.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: maybe not the best solution but ... try mine http://selvinlistsyncsample.codeplex.com/ ... some numbers: Goods table: 53335 rows/13 columns, Prices table: 11583/3, Customers table .. depends on which user synchronize data ... and it works good :) ... it's pretty simple to use this library :) ... anyway look here http://www.google.com/events/io/2010/sessions/developing-RESTful-android-apps.html ... i know, i know it takes 1h but still it's worth to watch this

Comment: I've sat through a few IO sessions so what's another one right?  Thanks for the resources...looking into them now!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have an API/service yet, you need to write one on top of your database.

I can think of two approaches, depending upon your use case.

1. Paging: Setup an API that supports paging, and show the results page by page. The user can't possibly view 10000 records in one go.
2. Search and suggest: Try creating a suggestion list, when the user starts typing out something. Fetch results that start with the initial characters entered. However, the API should limit the results to a comfortable number, so that you don't have to parse a lot.

Depending on your use case, you could try one of these.

Comment: So it looks as though paging is going to be where I head with this.  Also, is there a programmer friendly way to go about authenticating users on the server?  I don't want to use the word "easy", but for the sake of integration I would like to put my focus on offering content to users and not authenticating them.